# custom cell not appear when loading new views objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, storyboard

I create a UITableView programmatically with different cells and sections that connects to the other views in storyboard

**But if you check the story board absence view has custom cell with check box sections that it's not appear here**

**My question is:**

**why it doesn't shows the custom cell?,would you please helping me**

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"WorkTime"]){

    [segue.destinationViewController setTitle:@"WorkTime"];
}if([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"Absence"]){
    [segue.destinationViewController setTitle:@"Absence"];
}if([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"Compensation"]){
    [segue.destinationViewController setTitle:@"Compensation"];
}
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSMutableArray *keys = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *contents = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


NSString *workKey = @"work";
NSString *absKey = @"absence";
NSString *comKey = @"compensation";

[contents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Work Time", nil] forKey:workKey];
[contents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Absence", nil] forKey:absKey];
[contents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Compensation", nil] forKey:comKey];

[keys addObject:workKey];
[keys addObject:absKey];
[keys addObject:comKey];

[self setSectionKeys:keys];
[self setSectionContents:contents];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *key = [[self sectionKeys] objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
NSArray *contents = [[self sectionContents] objectForKey:key];
NSString *contentForThisRow = [contents objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

[[cell textLabel] setText:contentForThisRow];
return cell;

}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
_selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
[self.tableView reloadData];

//case1
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"WorkTime" sender:self];
//case2
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Absence" sender:self];
//case3
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Compensation" sender:self];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Your custom cell should have a unique cell identifier. You need to pass that unique cell identifier to `-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`.

What have you used as your cell identifier?

Answer (score 0):

you should use NSLOG to be sure that you are going to different views, I think you are always in a same view is the reason that you cann't see the new changes