# connect uitableviewcells to diffrent viws via segue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

I create a UITableView programmatically with different cells and sections that connects to the other views in storyboard like below picture:

**My question is:**

**how can I connect these 3 cells to these different views ,would you please helping me**

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *key = [[self sectionKeys] objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
NSArray *contents = [[self sectionContents] objectForKey:key];
NSString *contentForThisRow = [contents objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

[[cell textLabel] setText:contentForThisRow];
return cell;

}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
_selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
[self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

**Edit:**
When I use this method It just load the WorkTime view even if user select the absence cell,
Does any one knows why ?

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
  _selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
[self.tableView reloadData];
//maybe you could use a switch/case here, to assign the correct string to the segue identifier.
 switch (indexPath.row){
    case 0:
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"test" sender:self];
        break;
    case 1:
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"set" sender:self];
        break;
    case 2:
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"get" sender:self];
        break;
 }
 }
```

Comment: Is there a difference between this and your previous question? [custom cell not appear when loading new views objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899355/custom-cell-not-appear-when-loading-new-views-objective-c)

Answer (score 1):

Your last method is the way you want to go, but by the looks of it, you need to be checking `indexPath.section` not `indexPath.row`

Comment: @justin what i meant in my answer is the way you have it in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is more or less correct, but you need to check the section, not the row by the looks of the rest of your code.